# Determine if the following is true. If $m^*(E) >0$, then $E$ contains a non-empty open set.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Determine if the following is true. If $m^*(E) >0$, then $E$ contains a non-empty open set.

By definition $$m^*(E)= \inf Z_E, \text{where $Z_E = \{\sum_{j=1}^\infty \ell(I_j) : E \subset \cup_{j=1}^\infty I_j$} \}.$$

Now if $E$ does not contain a non-empty open set, then $\cup_{j=1}^\infty I_j$ must not also contain any non-empty open sets since by construction the cover $\cup_{j=1}^\infty I_j$ is constructed from countable many non-empty open sets? Thus the question would become is there any set for which the Lebesugue cover isn't constructed form open sets but has measure greater than zero?

Answer (score 5):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, $E:=[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ has Lebesgue measure 1 but empty interior, so it cannot contain any open subset.

Comment: How is it true that $[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$ has empty interior?

Comment: Every open interval contains a rational.

Answer (score 3):

Take a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set). Such a set has empty interior, but it Lebesgue measure is greater than $0$.

Comment: Thanks! How is the interior related to the problem here?

Comment: A set contains a non-empty open set if and only if its interior is not empty.